# DataModel data refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-modeling

I have tables in my database and I create my datamodel using datamodel framework.

I can select a row from my database correctly, but when I update a row in my database, I can not see the changings on my query.

For example: I select a data and a field looks "1". Then I change data to "2" in the database.

Select again in my program, it says "1". why is that happening? should I use a refresh function or something else?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean Entity Framework. Do you call "SaveChanges" on your database context?

Comment: thanks TSungur. it is entitiy frmaework. i dont insert or update any data within my program. i change data in ms-sql table. after change data, i can not see new data in my program.